# Having Maven Plugins in IntelliJ IDEA without Maven Installation in Computer

Tags: maven, intellij-idea

I just started to use Maven and IntelliJ IDEA.

I imported a project into IntelliJ IDEA which requires Maven. I didn't install Maven to my computer but I have 2 plugins in IntelliJ IDEA named as "Maven" and "Maven Extension". And the code I have is running without any dependency problem.

In that case, do I still need to install Maven from the web or just the plugins in the IntellJ are enough for projects with Maven?

Can we say that for every project? If someone can explain the logic behind I would be very happy.

Thanks a lot!

Comment: IJ comes bundled with it's own copy of Maven.  You're good to go.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Intellij comes with a bundled version of Maven (see File -> Settings -> Build, Execution, Deployment -> Build Tools -> Maven; the property 'Maven home directory' on that screen by defaults points to 'Bundled (Maven 3)').

You don't have to, but you can still install your own version of Maven, and point that property to it. It has the advantage of being able to run maven from the command-line, which is a better guarantee of build-stability (i.e. building the same project in different environments with the same result) than building directly inside of your IDE. And often is way more helpful in investigating build problems.